# Parsing Error with Streaming Data from Vercel Edge Function in Next.js Production Environment

Tags: json, next.js, vercel

In my Next.js application, I'm streaming data from a Vercel Edge Function. While streaming works correctly on my local development server, I encounter JSON parsing errors in the production environment. The console log shows a series of errors with the message

```
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unterminated string at line 1 column 23 of the JSON data.
```

It's been suggested that the stream might be fragmented due to factors like network latency and physical infrastructure distance. Vercel's documentation on streaming caveats supports this notion [here](https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/functions/edge-functions/streaming#caveats).

I've implemented an accumulator to handle the incoming stream and process JSON strings whenever a newline character is encountered. Although this approach works well on localhost, it's not sufficient in production, and I'm unable to render the streamed data due to incorrect parsing.

I'm looking for a solution to handle streaming data robustly in production and avoid parsing errors. Below is the relevant portion of my code:

```
// ...
// Temporary variable to hold the assistant's response
let assistantResponse = '';

let jsonAccumulator = ''; // Accumulator for reconstructing JSON strings
const reader = response.body.getReader();
const decoder = new TextDecoder('utf-8');
while (true) {
  const { done, value } = await reader.read();
  if (done) {
    break;
  }
  jsonAccumulator += decoder.decode(value, { stream: true });

  // Process JSON strings whenever a new line is encountered
  while (jsonAccumulator.includes('\n')) {
    const lineEnd = jsonAccumulator.indexOf('\n');
    const line = jsonAccumulator.slice(0, lineEnd).trim();
    jsonAccumulator = jsonAccumulator.slice(lineEnd + 1);

    if (line.startsWith('data: ')) {
      const jsonChunkStr = line.substring(6);
      if (jsonChunkStr.trim() === '[DONE]') {
        break;
      } else {
        try {
          const jsonChunk = JSON.parse(jsonChunkStr);
          if (jsonChunk.choices && jsonChunk.choices[0].delta.content) {
            assistantResponse += jsonChunk.choices[0].delta.content;
            setMessages((prevMessages) => [
              ...prevMessages.slice(0, -1),
              { role: 'assistant', content: assistantResponse },
            ]);
          }
        } catch (error) {
          console.error('JSON parse error:', error);
          console.error('Chunk string:', jsonChunkStr);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
// ...
```

Comment: Hi Martin. Did you find a solution? I'm getting the exact same issue right now. I've tried adding in return characters to my upstream generator which fixes it most of the time, but not always.